# What is the risk if I don't have a passphrase associated with CA private key?

Tags: certificate-authority, openssh

I understand that it is better to use a passphrase for SSH private keys so that even if someone accesses your machine, they can't simply SSH into a protected machine using your keys.

My question is specific to a certificate authority. Suppose I have an application which takes user keys and signs them using the CA key and returns a signed certificate, what is my risk if I don't have a passphrase associated with the key? No user(except for the admins of course) would have a direct access to the private key.

I don't mind creating a key with a passphrase (it is very easy) but I was just wondering about the risks associated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the signing process is performed automatically on a machine (through the application you mentioned), having a passphrase adds a minor extra protection.

The reason for this is that to perform the automatic signing task (assuming you invoke openssl utility), the passphrase must be stored at least in memory. If you want your application to survive crashes and reboots, it will also be stored on disk.

This means if your machine is breached while the program is running, the hackers can get both the private key and passphrase. Thus adding a passphrase will not prevent leaking of the private key, and the consequences of invalidating all certificate signed by this CA.

However the passphrase can still protect against certain specific attacks:

1. If you send or expose the private key by mistake (for example send it to a customer instead of CA public key)
2. If your application always reads the key from a keyboard and doesn't store it on disk, the private key will be safe when the machine is turned off.

(of course there's also a chance of the key to be swapped to disk if special measures are not used, and then the key could still be taken from the disk)

Answer (score 3):

So, the cost of loosing control of your CA is that you would need to make the compromise public, eliminate that CA from all trust stores, and reissue all certificates that are currently valid and signed by that CA.

So... how certain are you of any given security control on the key pair in light of that expense?

The answer varies widely due to the risk/value/scope of what you are securing with your CA.  If this is three servers in your basement and three mobile phones used by you and 2 friends, the scope is much different from a commercial grade CA system, a corporate CA system or a defense system...

In most of my experience, the cost of securing a CA key pair is *minor* in comparison to the cost of loosing face, having to reissue every cert (that includes refreshing CRLs and OCSP servers, if applicable), and having to update every trust store... not to mention contacting any other parties who were relying on your trust store, or going public about a data breach in your security infrastructure... but then I like high stakes systems.

In my experience, the CA systems I work with go a lot farther than a password on the key pair.  Root CA keys are kept offline and under two man physical access control with heavy auditing.  Intermediate CAs are heavily secured behind firewalls, DMZ's, heavy auditing of access, separation of control, and FIPS grade hardware that keeps the key on a box that is tamper resistant and TEMPEST secure.  But I admit - I work with CAB certified, or govt. grade systems... I don't run small scale CAs.

Mileage always varies depending on risk.  If it was a 4 hour job to rekey/reset trust and you think it will be 1 hour of pain every week when you've forgotten your key pair password and had to go crack it or dig out a locked up password... then if you only estimate rekeying due to break-in as a once a quarter event, you probably save yourself the hassle by NOT setting a key password.  (1 rekey = 4 hours, 1Xweek for 12 weeks of lost password recovery = 12 hours... )

Comment: If the private CA key was stolen in a breach, and there were new certificates signed issued around that time, there is always a possibility the passphrase was stolen as well. So having a passphrase doesn't really add much to security in this scenario.